# separate_columns for tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Let's say I had a survey question that read:

What did you eat?

- [ ] apple
- [ ] pear
- [x] banana
- [x] grapes

Now, I have the endorsed options as comma-separated strings in one variable.
I wrote myself a little helper to turn this comma-separated list of answers into boolean dummies showing whether each box was checked.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  ate = c("apple", "apple, pear, banana", "banana, grapes", NA_character_, ""),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

separate_columns <- function(df, col, convert = TRUE, sep = ", ") {
  colname <- deparse(substitute(col))
  # sorry about this ugly non-rlang approach, hoping not to reuse this
  df$.splitcol <- df %>% pull(colname)
  separate_rows(df, .splitcol, convert = convert, sep = sep) %>% 
    mutate(.splitcol = stringr::str_c(colname, "_", .splitcol), value = 1) %>% 
    mutate(.splitcol = if_else(is.na(.splitcol), stringr::str_c(colname, "_nonresponse"), .splitcol)) %>% 
    spread(.splitcol, value, fill = 0) %>% 
    select(-colname)
}

separate_columns(df, ate)
```

Gets me to this:

`x ate_apple ate_banana ate_grapes ate_nonresponse ate_pear
  1         1          0          0               0        0
  2         1          1          0               0        1
  3         0          1          1               0        0
  4         0          0          0               1        0
  5         0          0          0               1        0`

Writing the helper felt clunky, and I feel like I'm missing a more *tidyverse* way of accomplishing the same transformation (despite lots of searching).

Also, I found no easy way for missings to propagate using this method (I'd prefer if all dummies would be missing if the response was NA, but 0 if it was an empty string). So, I'd rather get this

`x ate_apple ate_banana ate_grapes    ate_pear
  1         1          0          0          0
  2         1          1          0          1
  3         0          1          1          0
  4         NA         NA         NA         NA
  5         0          0          0          0`

**Is there a nicer *tidyverse* way?**

Comment: If the last one is the expected output, it is not clear from your original post

Comment: @akrun It's what I intended to communicate with "I'd prefer if all dummies would be missing if the response was NA, but 0 if it was an empty string" but yes, I understood I had to add an example after I saw your initial answer.

Answer (score 2):

After changing into 'long' format by splitting the 'ate' column by the delimiter `,`, create a column of 1 and `spread` from 'long' to 'wide'

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  separate_rows(ate, sep=", ", convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(ate = replace(ate, is.na(ate), "NA"), 
         n = paste(NA ^ (ate == "NA")), 
         ate = paste0("ate_", replace(ate, ate == "", "nonresponse" ))) %>% 
  spread(ate, n, fill = "0") %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-x, -ate_NA), 
   funs(replace(as.integer(.), ate_NA=="NA", NA_integer_))) %>% 
   select(-ate_NA)
#   x ate_apple ate_banana ate_grapes ate_nonresponse ate_pear
#1 1         1          0          0               0        0
#2 2         1          1          0               0        1
#3 3         0          1          1               0        0
#4 4        NA         NA         NA              NA       NA
#5 5         0          0          0               1        0
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did, except for the nonresponse dummy line. The missings also don't propagate as requested.

Comment: @Ruben Sorry, didn't notice it earlier.  Updated

Comment: I tried to clarify my request, especially the part about missings. This isn't quite what I meant. Thanks for the `quosure` example though, I still find this very difficult to get right.

Comment: Thanks, you're very fast. But please look at the last example df in my last edit. I'd like to be able to get rid of the non-response column and have NA for all dummies when the character var was NA.

Comment: @Ruben Ok, i updated the post with the edits you have.  Wrapping the function is similar, but have to do some changes.  I don't have time to work on it now

Answer (score 2):

I take a different approach, by first extracting want was there to eat and then matching it in the data:

```
total_eat_list <- map(df$ate, str_split, patter = ",") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  str_trim() %>% 
  na.exclude() %>% 
  unique()
```

Remove empty strings:

```
total_eat_list <- total_eat_list[total_eat_list != ""]
total_eat_list 
# [1] "apple"  "pear"   "banana" "grapes"
```

Now lets map everything in the original data:

```
map_df(total_eat_list, ~
  df %>% 
  mutate(ate_what = str_c("ate_", .x), 
         ind = case_when(str_detect(string = df$ate, .x) ~ 1, 
                         !str_detect(string = df$ate, .x) ~ 0, 
                         TRUE ~ NA_real_))) %>% 
  spread(ate_what, ind) %>% 
  select(-ate) 

# A tibble: 5 x 5
#       x ate_apple ate_banana ate_grapes ate_pear
#   <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1         1          0          0        0
# 2     2         1          1          0        1
# 3     3         0          1          1        0
# 4     4        NA         NA         NA       NA
# 5     5         0          0          0        0
```

The nice thing is that `NA`s are infectious for the `str_`-functions.

---

As function:

```
who_ate_what <- function(data, col) {
  col <- enquo(col)
  col_name <- quo_name(col)

  match_list <- data %>%
    select(!!col) %>%
    map(str_split, patter = ",") %>%
    unlist() %>%
    str_trim() %>%
    na.exclude() %>%
    unique()

  match_list <- match_list[match_list != ""]

  map_df(match_list, ~
           data %>%
           mutate(matches = str_c(!!col_name, "_", .x),
                  ind = case_when(str_detect(string = !!col, .x) ~ 1,
                                  !str_detect(string = !!col, .x) ~ 0,
                                  TRUE ~ NA_real_)
           )) %>%
    spread(matches, ind) %>% 
    select(-!!col)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is way too verbose I'm sure, but I guess its a start.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  ate = c("apple", "apple, pear, banana", "banana, grapes", NA_character_, ""),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df %>% 
  nest(-x) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, ~str_split(.x$ate, ",") %>% unlist())) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  group_by(x, data) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(data, n, fill = NA) %>%
  select(-`<NA>`) %>%
  mutate(rs = rowSums(.[2:ncol(.)],na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  gather(nm, val, -x, -rs) %>%
  mutate(val = case_when(
    is.na(val) & rs > 0 ~ "0",
    is.na(val) & rs == 0 ~ "NA",
    !is.na(val) ~ as.character(val)
  ), val = as.numeric(val)) %>%
  spread(nm, val, fill = NA) %>%
  select(-rs, -V1)

#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#>       x ` banana` ` grapes` ` pear` apple banana
#>   <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1         0         0       0     1      0
#> 2     2         1         0       1     1      0
#> 3     3         0         1       0     0      1
#> 4     4        NA        NA      NA    NA     NA
#> 5     5         0         0       0     0      0
```

**EDIT**
Lets wrap this into a function and take care of the name issue. I adopted the splitting from your original function to make the use of quosures easier.

```
my_sep_fun <- function(data, col){
  col <- enquo(col)
  col_name <- quo_name(col)

  data %>% 
   separate_rows(!!col, sep =', ', convert = TRUE) %>%
   group_by(x, !!col) %>%
   summarise(n = n()) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   spread(!!col, n, fill = NA) %>%
   select(-`<NA>`) %>%
   mutate(rs = rowSums(.[2:ncol(.)],na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   gather(nm, val, -x, -rs) %>%
   mutate(val = case_when(
    is.na(val) & rs > 0 ~ "0",
    is.na(val) & rs == 0 ~ "NA",
    !is.na(val) ~ as.character(val)
   ), val = as.numeric(val)) %>%
   spread(nm, val, fill = NA) %>%
   select(-rs, -V1) %>%
   rename_at(vars(2:ncol(.)), funs(paste0(!!col_name,"_", .)))
}

my_sep_fun(df, ate)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>       x ate_apple ate_banana ate_grapes ate_pear
#>   <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1         1          0          0        0
#> 2     2         1          1          0        1
#> 3     3         0          1          1        0
#> 4     4        NA         NA         NA       NA
#> 5     5         0          0          0        0
```

Created on 2018-08-20 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This yields the desired output (except for the column names, but that's easy to fix), thanks. But yeah it seems very verbose to achieve something rather simple and wouldn't be easy to turn into a function..

Comment: Although I agree that this is probably not the simplest solution, It wouldn't be very difficult to wrap into a function. It would just involve wrapping the column names into quosures and then referencing those columns as shown in akruns answer

Answer (score 0):

One solution, much less verbose, in just three lines. Once you have the dataframe:

First, separate the values in each cell:

```r
df <- separate_rows_(df, 'ate')
```

Second, dummify every answer using the function `dummify` from `DataExplorer`:

```r
df <- DataExplorer::dummify(df, 'ate')
```

Third, aggregate the redundant rows like that:

```r
df <- aggregate(df[,2:6], by=df$x, FUN= sum)
```

(you could also apply a `max` function here since you want to capture all 1's in the columns).

Done!